# Safari mobile and Firefox mobile are not resizing and painting a Canvas that is drawn using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, html5-canvas

I have an HTML page that has a `canvas` where a roulette is being drawn with JS

According to [CanIuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=canvas) website then canvas functionality is supported in Firefox 68 and Safari 4 to 13

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>RuLetras 2020.06.20 - MGG</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
    </head>
    <body style="font-size:14px">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                    <label for="txtOptions">Opciones ruleta:</label>
                    <input id="txtOptions" type="text" value="a,e,i,o,u">

                    <button id="btnCreate" type="button">Crear</button>
                    
                    <br>
                    <label for="selectRoulette">Usar ruleta:</label>
                    <select id="selectRoulette" name="selectRoulette">
                    </select>

                    <button id="btnChangeColors" type="button" disabled>Cambiar colores</button>

                    <button id="btnSpin" type="button" disabled>Girar !</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                    <canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:0px solid #d3d3d3;">
                    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ruletra.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The size of the canvas is changed using JS to fill the width and height of the innerWindows and the background has been fill to gray to see if the canvas is being drawn.

The published version https://tender-lamport-b738a7.netlify.app/ is showing up correctly in Chrome Mobile but in Firefox Mobile 68.9.0 and Safary is only showing the form but not the canvas with the roulette.

Since I am very new at debugging HTML and Javascript in mobile browsers I need to know how can I debug or determine why is not painting correclty (similar to accesing the Developer Tools)

And for this particular case I also need some pointers about what can be causing the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying unsucessfully to use Babel to transpile my code into a more standard (older) javascript I found someone here in stackoverflow that mentioned https://jshint.com/ to test you javascript for possible compatbility issues.

In my case I was using `class`, `arrow functions` and other things

The code has now been updated and is working

There is also a jshint plugin for Visual Studio Code as well as many other linters - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.jshint

Hope this helps someone in the future

[image]